# How can i add Google Ads Tracking code in Success Page

Tags: magento-1.9, order-success-page, google-adwords

Here is my code :

```
<!-- Event snippet for Final Page conversion page -->
<script>
  wtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-23232323223232/23232323233434343443',
      'value': 0.0,
      'currency': 'INR',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```

How can i add in success page?

Comment: if you have access to your theme files you can add it that way by going to your theme directory /checkout/success.phtml

Comment: @DavaGordon Shall i add directly to core files, what about magento version upgrade issue?

Comment: Never edit the core, if you have a custom theme copy the success.phtml from the base theme to your theme. same structure and that should overwrite what is shown. once you have done that edit the new file within your theme and save and recache the site and all should be well

Comment: Thank you for clear details.

Comment: hope your issue is resolved :)

Comment: one last doubt, i am using magento one page checkout, where i can find my default success.phtml page, then only i am add to to my theme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97573/discussion-between-zus-and-dava-gordon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme go to the checkout folder and edit success.phtml

If you do not have a success.phtml in your theme then to overwrite this you can copy the one from the base magneto theme folder which can be found

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout
```

copy the file to your theme in the same directory

```
app/design/frontend/your/theme/template/checkout
```

Do any edits you need to the new success.phtml file placed in your theme and remember to flush the magento cache once you have done this

Your code should look like this

```
<?php 
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
?>

<!-- Event snippet for Final Page conversion page -->
<script>
  wtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-23232323223232/23232323233434343443',
      'value': <?php echo $order->getGrandTotal() ?>,
      'currency': 'INR',
      'transaction_id': '<?php echo $orderId ?>'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Does anything add to transaction_id?

Comment: I have updated my comment